# VSCode JSON Validation credentials/authentication for certain schemas

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to use JSON schemas that requires credentials to access.
So when I use VSCode I want to configure the following:
For all schema references in a JSON files that uses xdomain.com/blabla/* please perform basic authentication with username x and password y or bearer token.

And in my JSON file I just have

```
"$schema":"https://example.com/blabla/*/schemas/1.0.0/example.schema.json"
```

Is there any way to configure this?

Comment: you can't put the username and password in the URL? Or you don't want to?